# Why does this macrodef fail?

Tags: ant, build, jenkins

I am trying to print out a local timestamp for every target in a build xml. I have this macrodef to try and work around the same timestamp being printed every time.

```
<macrodef name="timestamp.echo"> 
    <attribute name="message"/> 
        <sequential> 
            <local name="current.time" />
                <tstamp> 
                    <format property="current.time" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss.SSS"/> 
                </tstamp> 
                    <echo message="${current.time}@{message}" />
        </sequential> 
</macrodef>
```

and this code sits at  the end of every target but within the target -

```
<timestamp.echo message="Mail sent" />
```

when I ran this on a local task it worked perfectly however when I run with Jenkins it fails. I get this error message -

```
Problem: failed to create task or type local
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.
```

I am struggling as I have declared the name and cannot see the cause of the problem. Any help is appreciated.

**ANSWER FOR FUTURE REFERENCES**

For earlier Ant versions I discovered this will do the job to create a local timestamp -

```
<target name="timestamp">
  <tstamp>
    <format property="current.time" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.SSS" />
  </tstamp>
  <echo message="${current.time} ${message}" />      
</target>
```

and then inserting this into a target will work -

```
      <antcall target="timestamp">
        <param name="message" value="Completed" />
      </antcall>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `<local>` task was added to Ant in [version 1.8](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/local.html). Upgrade Ant to at least version 1.8 or newer.

Otherwise, you may have to use the third-party Ant-Contrib's [`<var>` task](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/variable_task.html) to simulate scoped properties.

Comment: This is the correct answer, unfortunately I've been told upgrading is out of the question so I will investigate where to go from here.

Comment: Thanks. I was struggling for an hour. Your answer helped.